# Can i use SignalR with Xmpp?

Tags: xmpp, signalr, client-server

Currently, am working on client(web client) server application, am using `xmpp` framework to send and receive messages, `xmpp` is async communication, i have read articles on the internet, to create Asynchronous scalable web applications with real-time persistent long-running connections with `SignalR` is the best way. I want to know that can i use `SignalR` and `Xmpp` simultaneously?

Comment: You want to forward xmpp to signalr or do you want both in 1 website for the same message or do you want to replace xmpp with signalr?

Comment: I want to use xmpp for communication and signalr for updating user interface.

Comment: Your asp.net server needs the xmpp messages and pass them through to SignalR. Kinda missing the use case because SignalR doesn't update the UI itself.